# getResources does not work / undefined Java

Tags: java, android, undefined

I have a problem with caling the `getResources()` function in an standard class. All imports must be there to use the function. Is there any special class I need to extend my class?

Thanks for the immediate help.

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;

import android.content.res.Resources;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

//import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DbAdapter {

    public DbAdapter() {
     Resources res = getResources();//error: The method getResources() is undefined for the type DbAdapter
            //also tyed context.getResources()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`getResouces` is a method of a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).
So you can pass the context to your DbAdapter constructor and call `getResources` from it :

```
public DbAdapter(Context context) {
     Resources res = context.getResources();//error: The method getResources() is undefined for the type DbAdapter
            //also tied context.getResources()
}
```

Comment: use getApplicationContext to get the application context that you will be sending to DbAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If your Adapter is for example an ArrayAdapter, you can use this:

> `getContext().getResources();`

Answer (score 0):

Define `Context's` object  and then call all the `R.<Methods>` with the help of `context` object .

Eg:

```
Context ctx;
ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.Forgot_message);
```

Above code is working for me .