# How reference String in SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: string, reference, sqliteopenhelper, getstring

I have an activity that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and i want to reference a string from resources in my strings.xml

when i use: 
Resources res = getResources(); 
String Note = res.getString(R.string.M1Details);

i get error: The method getResources() is undefined for the type NotesSQL.DbHelper

i have also tried: 
String Note = getString(R.string.M1Details);

and i get: The method getString(int) is undefined for the type NotesSQL.DbHelper

i want to know how to properly reference strings from resources xml
thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4338439/1189831) is the same problem. Basically use `context.getResource()`.